# Devise gem(Ruby on Rails): The last signed_in always returns 127.0.0.1, How to get the real IP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, geolocation

I want to get the real IP of my system so that I can further get the location(using geocoder gem). I am using devise gem's trackable module to get the IP of the user. When I try to geocode the IP, it fails because the **last_signed_in_ip** returned by devise is always 127.0.0.1. I double checked the location permissions in the browser so that doesnt seem to be an issue as it is allowed to track location there. What can be wrong?

Also, is there a better way to find out one's location (apart from tracking IP address and then geocoding it?). Can the user be asked again to allow location tracking from within the application in case he has not allowed it or isnt aware of such setting?

Appreciate all the help in advance.

Thanks

Comment: Do you run your application behind proxy server like nginx or haproxy?

Comment: No, this is just my development environment and there is no proxy...

Comment: Do you access your app via `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` ?

Answer (score 0):

`request.remote_ip` will solve your problem...

it will never return you your own m/c address, instead If you need the remote address for (testing) your geocoding, I suggest adding 127.0.0.1 to your database table that matches IP addresses with locations

you can hardcode like this for testing purpose:

```
if request.remote_ip == '127.0.0.1'
  # Hard coded remote address
  '123.45.67.89'
else
  request.remote_ip
end
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt. Thats exactly what devise uses but for some reason it doesnt return the true address

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return your external IP address programmatically then you need to access your app from that address.

When you visit your app at localhost, `request.remote_ip` will return 127.0.0.1 because that is your localhost IP address.

To get around this you can either forward your development port (normally 3000) from your router to your PC and then access your app by entering your external IP address into your browser instead of localhost (eg: 123.123.123.123:3000).

Alternatively add your external IP address to your hosts file pointing to localhost (ie: `localhost 123.123.123.123`) and then browse to your app via your external IP address as above.